# JS- how would I make this into an ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, module, three.js, shader

Ok, I'm breaking apart the ShaderGlow example from https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html trying to bring it into my node app.

Author does everything in  tags in the html doc, but my whole app is in `app.js` and calls in ES6 modules from helper files.

The shader, before my tweaking, works like this:

```
var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
{
    uniforms:
    {
        "c":   { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        "p":   { type: "f", value: 1.4 },
        glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xffff00) },
        viewVector: { type: "v3", value: camera.position }
    },
    vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexShader'   ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
}   );
```

Where fragment and vertex shader are in their own 's:

```
<!-- ---------------- Custom Shader Code ------------------------ -->
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
uniform vec3 viewVector;
uniform float c;
uniform float p;
varying float intensity;
void main() 
{
    vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
    vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
    intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<!-- fragment shader a.k.a. pixel shader -->
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
uniform vec3 glowColor;
varying float intensity;
void main() 
{
    vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
    gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
}
</script>
```

So far I've tried doing:

```
import fragmentShader from './elements/GlowShaders.js';
import vertexShader from './elements/GlowShaders.js';

    var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
    {
            uniforms:
        {
            "c":   { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
            "p":   { type: "f", value: 1.4 },
            glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xffff00) },
            viewVector: { type: "v3", value: this.camera.position }
        },
        vertexShader:  vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
        side: THREE.FrontSide,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        transparent: true
    }   );
```

With GlowShader.js written like:

```
export default class vertexShader {
  uniform vec3 viewVector;
  uniform float c;
  uniform float p;
  varying float intensity;
  void main()
  {
      vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
    vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
    intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );

      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  }
}

export default class fragmentShader {
  uniform vec3 glowColor;
  varying float intensity;
  constructor() {
    vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
      gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
  }
}
```

Honestly very new to modules and this does not work. How can I break these special shader blocks into modules, or incorporate them in my app.js script?

Comment: Shader are a language of their own. They ain't JS. This is code that is executed on your graphics card. You have to pass the shader scripts exactly as they are to three.js (as strings)

Comment: check out [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/)

Comment: @Thomas good to know. How can I incorporate just the text then? Given that Im not working in <script> tags?

Comment: How to put a string in some JS code?

Comment: @Thomas What do I just paste the whole block of shader code in quotes after the "vertexShader:" parameter in customMaterial?

Comment: yes, but I'd either use template strings or use `JSON.stringify()` to properly serialize this multiline string. But that's exactly what `vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexShader'   ).textContent` does. *Find the script node with the id "vertexShader", get the `textContent` of that node and pass this text to the property `vertexShader`

Comment: Can you provide an answer where you put the code block into JSON.stringify or another format able to be read by the JS? Pasting straight into the parameter doesn't work, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you provide an answer where you put the code block into JSON.stringify or another format able to be read by the JS? Pasting straight into the parameter doesn't work, no.

```
const vertexShader = `
uniform vec3 viewVector;
uniform float c;
uniform float p;
varying float intensity;
void main() 
{
    vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
    vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
    intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}`;

const fragmentShader = `
uniform vec3 glowColor;
varying float intensity;
void main() 
{
    vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
    gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
}`;

var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms:
    {
        "c":   { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        "p":   { type: "f", value: 1.4 },
        glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xffff00) },
        viewVector: { type: "v3", value: camera.position }
    },
    vertexShader,
    fragmentShader,
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
});
```

or

```
var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms:
    {
        "c":   { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        "p":   { type: "f", value: 1.4 },
        glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xffff00) },
        viewVector: { type: "v3", value: camera.position }
    },
    vertexShader: "uniform vec3 viewVector;\nuniform float c;\nuniform float p;\nvarying float intensity;\nvoid main() \n{\n    vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );\n    vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );\n    intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );\n\n    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );\n}",
    fragmentShader: "uniform vec3 glowColor;\nvarying float intensity;\nvoid main() \n{\n    vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;\n    gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );\n}",
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
});
```